# Flexslider links not opening

Tags: jquery, flexslider

This is for a static html site. I am trying to get the slides to link to other pages on the site. The pointer shows when I click on the slides, but page does not open:

```
 <div class="flexslider">
         <ul class="slides">
        <li> <a href="page1.html"><img src="img/slide-1.jpg" alt="" ></a> </li>
        <li> <a href="page2.html"><img src="img/slide-2.jpg" alt="" ></a> </li>
        <li> <a href="page3.html"><img src="img/slide-3.jpg" alt="" ></a> </li>
        <li> <a href="page4.html"><img src="img/slide-4.jpg" alt="" ></a> </li>
        <li> <a href="page5.html"><img src="img/slide-5.jpg" alt="" ></a> </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

I have not altered any other code. Am I missing something? I don't know Jquery well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding this should work. Two ideas worth a try:

- make sure `pauseOnHover=false`
- set the z-index of a `<a>` element to 100

good luck!